# UIActivityViewController share apps list empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to share images to wechat by UIActivityViewController, my code is below

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"提示" message:@"已为您复制消息内容，请在分享内容框中粘贴！" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"知道了" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:array  applicationActivities:nil];
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
        [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:TRUE completion:nil];
    }];
    [alert addAction:cancel];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but the share pop menu get empty

[image]

where is wrong?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

EDIT:
I found my array is empty, because I add a wrong image into that array, image url is wrong. So my share pop menu is empty. Now, it solved! Thank u guys!

Comment: Are you checking it on simulator or device ?

Comment: yes, i checked it on iphone 6s, I post an image in question

Comment: UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:array  applicationActivities:nil]; for this code, what is in your "array", I found if I pass an array of UIImage it's empty, if I pass an array of String, it is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is occurs due to empty array so you need to pass filled array to ActivityController .

```
 NSArray * array = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pass your data"], [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];// this occur due to this
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:array  applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

Comment: /yes! u r right. but when I debug array, I checked it's not empty, why? this array contains an array of object which has image url.

Comment: add  that array in question .

Answer (score -1):

For sharing in Facebook you should have Facebook app installed in device.